# Does ifort support coarrays on mac

Tags: fortran, fortran-coarrays

So I followed all of the instructions on Intel site to get parallel studios and ifort installed on my MacBook Pro. I have confirmed I can correctly compile regular Fortran program and execute them, but I cannot seem to find any distinct answers as to if ifort on Mac supports coarrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [compiler documentation](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/data-types-constants-and-variables/variables-1/coarrays.html) for Intel Fortran version 19.1 says there is no support for coarray on macOS. It's available on Windows and Linux though.

Comment: This is the answer I was assuming would be it, I was just hoping I was wrong. Everything I was reading in documentation was basically not giving instructions for Mac but didn’t explicitly say not supported. Thank you!